# Velocity Template Not Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

I'm trying to use Velocity inside my Spring MVC site to template emails. I believe that everything would be fine if Velocity could find the template I want to use. I have a template at `/WEB-INF/emails/faultNotification.vm`. In my code, I have this:

```
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper (message, true);
helper.setTo (toAddresses);
helper.setSubject (subject);
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<> ();
model.put ("username", "nikitin");
model.put ("emailAddress", "nik.estep@gmail.com");
helper.setText (VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString (
                                 m_emailEngine,
                                 "faultNotification.vm",
                                 model), true);
helper.addAttachment (attachmentName,
                      new ByteArrayResource (attachment.toByteArray ()),
                      "application/zip");
m_sender.send (message);
```

In my XML, I have this:

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="file:/WEB-INF/emails" />
</bean>
<bean id="emailSender" class="com.tarigma.gem.communication.EmailSender">
    <constructor-arg ref="systemSettings" />
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine" />
</bean>
```

I have been reading any post I can find and from what I can tell, this should work, but Velocity cannot find the template when I go to use it (`ERROR VelocityEngine - ResourceManager: Unable to find resource 'faultNotification.vm' in any resource loader`). I don't want to put the template in `/WEB-INF/classes` because that's not what goes in that folder and there has to be a way to make this work. Any help would be appreciated, I lost all of yesterday trying to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your war is not deployed in exploded  form,  there is no file URL for you. 
I would try to configure :

http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/view/WebappResourceLoader.html

instead of file resource loader and use full path starting fom root of war